# Unaligned letters in itemize

Tags: beamer, itemize

I have a pretty simple problem. I need the following code to produce an aligned items

```
\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}
    
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \only<1>{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item i
            \end{itemize}
        }
        \only<2>{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item g
            \end{itemize}
        }
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However, it could be seen, that the lines are unaligned, and, since I want to present frames in a succession, breaks the visual expectations.

Every other letter seems to be ok, except for 'g'.

Comment: g descends below the baseline, i does not. You can add a `\strut`. BTW why entire lists when you can add `<>` to items

Comment: @ daleif, cause it is MWE, in reality I have images along the way

Comment: @dEmigOd Then please make a minimal working example that reproduces your actual problem.

Comment: The example is MWE, it presents the problem, the comment above provides the solution.